# How to solve following auto-layout constrains problems?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I am using auto-layout inside my app and I can't manage to make constrains ok. I will need some help (kinda new to auto-layout)

My views and constrains:

[image]

Current result on iPhone 6 plus (smaller screen does not show nothing):

[image]

**Expected result**:

It should make views smaller and at the same time make space between views smaller like this one:

[image]

How can i manage that?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you tried making a width constraint?  Add a width constraint that is >= whatever the minimum width you would accept.  Add that width to all views and make all have equal widths

Comment: tried for one view (and they all have equal width one with each other) now but views won't fit inside screen and size between them is same ( big ) ..it will show like 6 views

Comment: This might be a little advanced since you are new at auto layout, but you can add IBOutlet's to constraints.  ex (NSLayoutContraint*width;)  so if you add constraints to the spaces between each view then programmatically figure out what size that needs to be, you can set the width between all views so that they fit.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Check out my answer to see how I've done it. Thanks again!

Comment: Seems like that won't give you the same results on each device.  Glad I could help though!

Comment: It does. I have no explanation for this... Edited answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, found out the answer and it's kinda awkward but I was struggling for finding him and maybe it will help someone.

I solved by making views **bigger**:

[image]

And the result on iPhone 6+:

[image]

And on iPhone 4s:

[image]